# Why is it that my form does not redirect me to the route im passing?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

Im doing a CRUD app with Java using Servlets and i have a jsp file as a list of many users where i have a button to edit my row. As i click on my button it should redirect me to ServletPacientes?Param=editar&dni=<%a.getDni()%>.

So this is my ListarPacientes.jsp: Where i have some scriplets and my html forms.

```
<body>
<% if (request.getSession().getAttribute("usuario") == null) { 
    request.getRequestDispatcher("Login.jsp").forward(request, response);
    throw new UsuarioNoLoggeadoException();
} 
 Usuario user = (Usuario)request.getSession().getAttribute("usuario");
 if (user.getTipo_usuario().getID() != 1) { 
        request.getRequestDispatcher("Home.jsp").forward(request, response);
        throw new UsuarioSinPermisoException();
} 
%>
<%
 if (request.getParameter("buscarLista") == null) {
        request.getRequestDispatcher("ServletPacientes?Param=list").forward(request, response);
 }
    List<Paciente> listaM = new ArrayList<Paciente>();
    if (request.getAttribute("listaPac") != null) {
        listaM = (List<Paciente>)request.getAttribute("listaPac");
    }
%>

<jsp:include page="Menu.jsp"></jsp:include>

<div class="table-title">
    <h3>Tabla Pacientes</h3>
</div>

<form method="post" action="ServletPacientes">

<div class="form-group">

          <label>Buscar: </label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="txtBuscar">
        </div>
        
        <div class="col-12">
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Buscar" name="btnBuscar">
        </div>

<table class="table-fill">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="text-left">Nombre</th>
            <th class="text-left">Apellido</th>
            <th class="text-left">DNI</th>
            <th class="text-left">Sexo</th>
            <th class="text-left">Direccion</th>
            <th class="text-left">Fecha de Nacimiento</th>
            <th class="text-left">Email</th>
            <th class="text-left">Telefono</th>
            <th class="text-left">Nacionalidad</th>
            
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody class="table-hover">

        <tr>
            <%
        for (Paciente a : listaM) {
    %>
        
        <tr>
            <form action="ServletPacientes" method="post">
            <td><%=a.getNombre()%></td>
            <td><%=a.getApellido()%></td>
            <td><%=a.getDni()%> <input type="hidden" name="dniPaciente" value="<%=a.getDni()%>" ></td>
            <td><%=a.getSexo()%></td>
            <td><%=a.getDireccion()%></td>
            <td><%=a.getFechaNac()%></td>
            <td><%=a.getCorreo()%></td>
            <td><%=a.getTelefono()%></td>
            <td><%=a.getNacionalidad()%></td>
            <td> <input type="submit" name="btnEliminar" value="Eliminar" class="btn btn-danger"></td>
            </form>
            <td> <a href="ServletPacientes?Param=editar&dni=<%=a.getDni()%>"><input type="submit" name="btnEditar" value="Editar" class="btn btn-warning"></a></td>
            
        </tr>

        <%
        }
    %>

    </tbody>
</table>
<br>
<div align="center">
    
    
 </div>

 </form>

</body>
```

As you can see i have de following tags

```
<td> <a href="ServletPacientes?Param=editar&dni=<%=a.getDni()%>"><input type="submit" name="btnEditar" value="Editar" class="btn btn-warning"></a></td>
```

So in each row i have this button where i call my Controller (Servlet) with the parameter "editar" and i pass the method getDni() of my class Paciente.

And here is my code of my ServletPacientes:

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        
        if(request.getParameter("Param")!=null)
        {
            String opcion = request.getParameter("Param").toString();
            
            switch (opcion) {
            case "previoInsert":
            {
                
                break;
            }
            case "list":
            {
                request.setAttribute("listaPac", negPac.listarPacientes()); 
                RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("/ListarPacientes.jsp?buscarLista=1");
                dispatcher.forward(request, response);
                break;
            }
            case "editar":
            {
                
                Paciente p = new Paciente();
                p = negPac.obtenerUno(request.getParameter("dniPaciente"));
                System.out.println(p);
                request.setAttribute("dniPac", p);  
                RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("/EditarPaciente.jsp");
                dispatcher.forward(request, response);
                break;
            }
            default:
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

The method above shows a switch where each case is a different parameter that im passing to my route. So when i click on my edit button instead of taking me to for example ServletPacientes?Param=editar&dni=20216447 it just redirects me to ServletsPacientes which is a blank page.

It looks like im never receiving the parameter editar neither the dni property. Becaus if i manually put on my url ServletPacientes?Param=editar&dni=20216447 it does takes me to the Edit view.

Comment: [How can I avoid Java code in JSP files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/how-to-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files)

Comment: @ScaryWombat i know about JST but this CRUD app im doing is project for college where it is mandatory to use JSP files thats why im trying to solve my issue this way and not using JST. Thanks tho.

Comment: JSTL goes inside your JSP rather than this very hard to read Java `<%` stuff.  Also I have no undertnding why you would `forward` then do `throw new UsuarioSinPermisoException();`

Comment: Also `<input type="submit" ` - will do a POST not a GET

Answer (score 0):

You essentially have the following structure:

```html
<form method="post" action="ServletPacientes">
    <a href="ServletPacientes?Param=editar&dni=<%=a.getDni()%>">
        <input type="submit" value="Editar">
    </a>
</form>
```

This means that when you click on this "Editar" button, a form submission will happen as a POST request. This request is supposed to be processed by a `doPost` method on the servlet side, and the URL would be `/ServletPacientes`. This is why you navigate to `/ServletPacientes`. The link in the wrapping `<a>` element will have no effect.

If you expect to navigate to something like `ServletPacientes?Param=editar&dni=20216447`, you'll have to make the nested `input` element a regular `button`, not a `submit`: `<input type="button" value="Editar">`.